# amazon cognito federated identities

Tags: amazon-cognito

We are integration Amazon Cognito Federated Identities in our application .

We are adding Login with Facebook and Login with Google as external identity providers.

Now assume that

1) first time user logs in with facebook with email id example@example.com .

2) During next visit ,same user log in with Google with same email id example@example.com

In above scenario , please let me know whether same Amazon Cognito federated entity will be used or not.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the above scenario the identityId will be different for both. The federation is based on the unique identifiers provided by the providers and not email address.

Comment: Hi, and whats the correct implementation to link both together ?

Comment: Cognito currently does not support this scenario. We have heard this from multiple customers and consider adding this in our roadmap.

Comment: Hi @RachitDhall, any changes in Cognito regarding this?